# How to call a function of child class inside a function of parent class

Tags: php

I want to call a function defined in child class from a function defined in the parent class for some logic. I am getting error of undefined function. How can I call this function. Here is my sample code.

```
<?php
 class First
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
        echo "First class is initiated.";
     }
     public function call_child()
     {
       $this->get_ouput();
     }
  }
  class Second extends First
  {
     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
     }
     public function get_output()
     {
        echo "Here is your output";
     }
  }
  $obj = new Second();
  $obj->call_child();

  ?>
```

Comment: Because you have typo in parent class. It's `get_output` and not `get_ouput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is spelling mistake in your function call name

```
<?php
 class First
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
        echo "First class is initiated.";
     }
     public function call_child()
     {
       $this->get_output(); //update the name here
     }
  }
  class Second extends First
  {
     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
     }
     public function get_output()
     {
        echo "Here is your output";
     }
  }
  $obj = new Second();
  $obj->call_child();

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo when calling the `get_output` method. However you should define the `First` class and `get_output` method as abstract in order to be extended/implemented by the other classes:

```
abstract class First
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
        echo "First class is initiated.";
     }

     abstract public function get_output();

     public function call_child()
     {
       $this->get_output();
     }
  }

  class Second extends First
  {
     public function get_output()
     {
        echo "Here is your output";
     }
  }

  $obj = new Second();
  $obj->call_child();
```

Note: the `Second` class may not define the constructor if it only calls the parent constructor.